# Using a static variable in an ASP.Net HttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, httpmodule

I'm using an HttpModule to intercept each requests to my website in order to assign them authentication cookies, this is only a preliminary version but I'm having a static List in my HttpModule and for each new request I'm adding an element in the list. For testing purposes I'm writing them all to the response in order to see if my method is working but it is only ever giving me two values no matter how many users are in the list.

Here is a sample of my code, I've kept it simple by replacing the list of users with a list of strings.

```
public class SCCModule : IHttpModule
{
    private static List<string> _users = new List<string>();

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += OnPreRequestHandlerExecute;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
    public void OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpResponse response = app.Context.Response;
        HttpRequest request = app.Context.Request;

        _users.Add("A user from " + DateTime.Now + "</br>");

        foreach(var u in _users)
        {
            response.Write(u);
        }
    }
}
```

When loading a sample index.html from the website, it gives me :

A user from 10/18/2012 3:37:33 PM

A user from 10/18/2012 3:37:35 PM

Info on my setup : I'm running IIS7.5 to which I've added a Module, it is the first in order of priorities of execution. I have enabled Debugging in the web.config. My VisualStudio is set to build debug configuration and there is a post build event to directly copy my DLL to the bin folder of my website. I am attaching myself to the w3wp.exe process in order to debug it.

An interesting fact : when debugging. The first two times I hit refresh on the index.html page are going to trigger my breakpoint and after that it won't. Any new URI that I enter will only hit the breakpoint two times.

So why is it that only two results seem to go through even though I can refresh ten times ?

Fiddler result : 
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'll make it more obvious in the text.

Comment: Try attaching Fiddler, your browser is probably not going back to the server and just showing you a cached page. My guess is the first two requests are for index.html and favicon.ico.

Comment: I Fiddled with it a bit and posted a screenshot. Not a cached request unfortunately. If I wait a bit, some minutes let's say, and I refresh I can get two new results. But then pressing F5 again won't show up new results unless I wait again.

Comment: Actually the problem was in IIS all along. Output caching was preventing new pages from being sent between an interval. Still not sure why I was allowed to request two new pages until the caching started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in IIS itself. Output caching was enabled thus the server was not sending any new pages even though the client was requesting new ones.

To result the issue I went to Output Caching -> Edit Feature Settings... -> I unchecked both Enable Cache and Enable Kernel cache.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser has cached the resources such as html, images and css.

Once browser has cached them, they won't be asked again unless you click on Ctrl+F5 in IE.

You can view the requests using Request.Path.

```
HttpRequest request = app.Context.Request;
_users.Add("A user from " + DateTime.Now + " - " + 
    app.Context.Request.Path + "</br>");
```

Comment: I checked fiddler and it doesn't look like any content is cached. There is only one nearly blank page so far for debugging. No images or CSS to cache yet.

Comment: ASPX page will send request to server each time you refresh, but HTML page is not. Click Ctrl+F5 if you want HTML page to reload.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<location path="data">
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="NoControl" />
    </staticContent>
    <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```